# convert & delimited String to a java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a method can convert & delimited String to a java class?

```
 Foo foo = Foo.fromString("name1=a&name2=b");
```

I am coding the twitter api: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/access_token. the response is

I need need a function do the blow things for me.

```
 String respnse = "oauth_token=6253282-eWudHldSbIaelX7swmsiHImEL4KinwaGloHANdrY&oauth_token_secret=2EEfA6BG3ly3sR3RjE0IBSnlQu4ZrUzPiYKmrkVU&user_id=6253282&screen_name=twitterapi";

 String [] resParas = respnse.split("&");

        for(String respara : resParas){
            if(respara.indexOf("oauth_token=")>=0){
                int index = "oauth_token=".length();
                access_token = respara.substring(index);
            }else if(respara.indexOf("oauth_token_secret=")>=0){
                int index = "oauth_token_secret=".length();
                access_token_secret = respara.substring(index);
            }else if(respara.indexOf("user_id=")>=0){
                int index = "user_id=".length();
                user_id = respara.substring(index);
            }else if(respara.indexOf("screen_name=")>=0){
                int index = "screen_name=".length();
                screen_name = respara.substring(index);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Very limited information. Please edit your question to make it more readable and understandable.

Comment: Not sure why you would do that, but https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString--

Comment: @JBNizet updated question.

Comment: That doesn't make anything clearer.

Comment: There is no controller, I need a function do the same action like controller get the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.18.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) for this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString("http://twitter.com/oauth?oauth_token=6253282-eWudHldSbIaelX7swmsiHImEL4KinwaGloHANdrY&oauth_token_secret=2EEfA6BG3ly3sR3RjE0IBSnlQu4ZrUzPiYKmrkVU&user_id=6253282&screen_name=twitterapi")
    .build()
    .getQueryParams();
```

Will give you a map with all params:

```
{oauth_token=[6253282-eWudHldSbIaelX7swmsiHImEL4KinwaGloHANdrY], oauth_token_secret=[2EEfA6BG3ly3sR3RjE0IBSnlQu4ZrUzPiYKmrkVU], user_id=[6253282], screen_name=[twitterapi]}
```